# best key, value container where key is string and value is type

Tags: c#, .net, containers

What is the suggested key, value container where the key is always of type string, and the value is a type?  The container will not be larger than 100 items.  Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `Dictionary<string, Type>`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, it pales in comparison with the `Max100ItemsDictionary<string, Type>`.

Comment: Appears you have created some debate.  Is that 100 a hard constraint that must be placed on the collection?

Comment: @ant do you want to restrict item's count in the dictionary ? and do you mean a **custom type** or **type of Type** by `the value is a type` ?

Comment: I am not interested in restricting the count.  I meant type of Type.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely go with standard `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. The only improvement you can make is based on your *there will be no more than 100 items* condition.

Use `new Dictionary<string, MyType>(int capacity)` constructor when creating dictionary, it will prevent underlying storage from reallocating when new items are added.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, MyType>(100);
```

Comment: specifying capacity won't limit the item's count.

Comment: _"The capacity of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is the number of elements that can be added to the Dictionary<TKey, TValue> before **resizing is necessary**. As elements are added to a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, the **capacity is automatically increased as required by reallocating the internal array**."_ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk84bxf4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Selman22 But he did not say that would limit the count.  Only prevent  reallocating.

Comment: @Blam you'r right sorry,I misunderstood the question

Comment: @Blam: where did OP say that he wants to prevent reallocating? The container/collection should "not be larger than 100 items".

Comment: @TimSchmelter Maybe the question is not 100% clear. I think he wants a collection which will be used to hold up to 100 items. If that's the case, `Dictionary` is just fine, and you can make it a little better specifying capacity. Do you think he asks for *collection which prevents you from adding more than 100 items*?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Marcin is the one the stated it would prevent reallocating.   Still seems like a good idea to me. +1

Comment: I took the less than 100 as a tuning parameter - not hard constraint.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: i don't see the use of such a restrictive collection but i'm not OP. It just seems to be more natural to ask for a collection with a maximum size instead of  a minimum capacity. The latter is simply too technical for someone who doesn't know a dictionary.

Comment: Seriously, you're overthinking this. The OP clearly hasn't met a dictionary yet and could care less about allocation. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble suggesting anything other than the standard .net [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you need concurrency there is also a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)